# Gaufrette and Dropbox adapter: Dropbox_Exception_Forbidden: Forbidden

Tags: zend-framework2, dropbox-php

I'm getting the error below when I'm running $filesystem->has('foo'). What am I doing wrong?

Dropbox_Exception_Forbidden: Forbidden. This could mean a bad OAuth request, or a file or folder already existing at the target location. Invalid or missing signature